# wordpress manage theme option disabled

Tags: wordpress, customization, dashboard

I was trying to add phone number on the right hand side of my header.  So I went to Appearance customize and change under site title and tagline enter the phone number.
  But later Want to change to but all three options side title & tagline, navigation and static
  frontpage menu is disabled when i try to click the arrow it dosen't work.
Here's [a link for website](http://kensingtoncameras.co.uk/).
[Click here for image](http://kensingtoncameras.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Screen-Shot-2014-08-04-at-11.23.17.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a JavaScript error in your theme when viewing the customisation pane.  JavaScript errors can (sometimes) cause unrelated areas to not function properly as the JavaScript engine essentially falls over.

I would suggest trying the same with a stock theme (Twenty Twelve, for example), so you can find if it is a theme-specific problem.  If it is a problem with the theme then you can consult with the author of the theme.

Comment: Yes, Twenty Twelve theme works fine, Thanks for your help I will consult author of the theme